# How do I install an apk on the sd card only?

Tags: android, installation, apk

I attempting to install an apk on to the sd-card only. I can install apks that are under a certain file size, but ones over a certain file size will only install on the internal memory. (I need to install to sd card)

There are no tmp files in /mnt/security/asec

```
# ls /mnt/secure/asec
ls /mnt/secure/asec
com.home.version2-2.asec
```

Log from attempting "adb install -r -s version1-debug.apk"

```
I/PackageHelper( 5663): Size of container 40 MB
W/ActivityManager( 5127): No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///sdcard/tmp/version1-debug.apk
D/VoldCmdListener( 1461): asec list
D/VoldCmdListener( 1461): asec create smdl2tmp1 40 fat {} 10009
W/logwrapper(28481): Unable to background process (No such file or directory)
I//system/bin/newfs_msdos( 1461): /system/bin/newfs_msdos: warning, /dev/block/dm-0 is not a character device
I//system/bin/newfs_msdos( 1461): /system/bin/newfs_msdos: Skipping mount checks
I//system/bin/newfs_msdos( 1461): Bogus heads from kernel - setting sane value
I//system/bin/newfs_msdos( 1461): Bogus sectors from kernel - setting sane value
I//system/bin/newfs_msdos( 1461): /system/bin/newfs_msdos: 2599 clusters too few clusters for FAT16, need 4096
I/logwrapper( 1461): /system/bin/newfs_msdos terminated by exit(1)
E/Vold    ( 1461): Format failed (unknown exit code 1)
E/Vold    ( 1461): ASEC FAT format failed (I/O error)
```

Log from attempting "adb install -r -s version2-debug.apk"

```
I/PackageHelper( 5663): Size of container 20 MB
W/ActivityManager( 5127): No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///sdcard/tmp/version2-debug.apk
D/VoldCmdListener( 1461): asec list
D/VoldCmdListener( 1461): asec create smdl2tmp1 20 fat {} 10009
W/logwrapper(28562): Unable to background process (No such file or directory)
I//system/bin/newfs_msdos( 1461): /system/bin/newfs_msdos: warning, /dev/block/dm-0 is not a character device
I//system/bin/newfs_msdos( 1461): /system/bin/newfs_msdos: Skipping mount checks
I//system/bin/newfs_msdos( 1461): Bogus heads from kernel - setting sane value
I//system/bin/newfs_msdos( 1461): Bogus sectors from kernel - setting sane value
I//system/bin/newfs_msdos( 1461): /dev/block/dm-0: 41600 sectors in 1300 FAT12 clusters (16384 bytes/cluster)
I//system/bin/newfs_msdos( 1461): bps=512 spc=32 res=1 nft=2 rde=512 sec=41643 mid=0xf0 spf=4 spt=63 hds=64 hid=0
I/Vold    ( 1461): Filesystem formatted OK
D/VoldCmdListener( 1461): asec path smdl2tmp1
```

I am wondering if it is anything to do with the formatting of the sd card. I have formatted the sd card on windows 7 with FAT and default allocation size. Is there anything I have missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To install .apk file into Sdcard use the below tag in Manifest file

**android:installLocation="preferExternal"**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal"
    ... >
```

If you declare "preferExternal", you request that your application be installed on the external storage, but the system does not guarantee that your application will be installed on the external storage. If the external storage is full, the system will install it on the internal storage. The user can also move your application between the two locations.

If you declare "auto", you indicate that your application may be installed on the external storage, but you don't have a preference of install location. The system will decide where to install your application based on several factors. The user can also move your application between the two locations.

for more details 
http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/install-location.html

Comment: According to the docs, adb install -s also makes sure it goes to external storage. Adding preferExternal to the manifest sill gives an error when trying to install the larger apk. Thanks though~

Comment: adb install -r -s version1-debug.apk
3508 KB/s (38278514 bytes in 10.655s)
        pkg: /sdcard/tmp/version1-debug.apk
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_CONTAINER_ERROR]

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing the same issue. Check if device mapper is enabled in your kernel.

> adb shell -> /dev/device-mapper